# iOS Swift / HTML-Code and PHP-Code in 'Strings'

Tags: php, html, ios, uiwebview

I tried the following coding for a '`UIWebView`:

```
let kapitel3 = "<html><head><title>Chapter 1</title></head><body><h1>This is a title!</h1></body></html>"
```

This HTML code works fine and `"UIWebView"` shows this code. But if I try to insert a PHP code within the HTML code like this:

`let kapitel3 = "<html><head><title>Chapter 1</title></head><body><h1>This is a title!</h1><?php print \"Hello world!\";?></body></html>"`

Then the PHP code won't be showed. Why doesn't 'UIWebView' translate this PHP code `<?php print \"Hello world!\";?>`?

Is it not possible to integrate PHP code in a **String** like above?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIWebView is only a simple web-browser...

You can't use php like that if you don't have a local webserver with a php interpreter installed!

You could load a php page from a remote url but your phone must have an active internet connection...

---

**Possible local solution:**
You can't use php locally, but in a UIWebView you can still use javascript!

I don't know what you are trying to do...but if you need your app to work offline (with local files) using php is the wrong approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your answer helped me and my problem is solved!

Comment: Glad I could help :) _Have a nice day!_